# Compile ebpf _kern.c outside the kernel tree and link stand alone libbpf to _user.c

Tags: kernel, clang, bpf, ebpf

**GOAL:** build an ebpf program outside the kernel tree using stand alone `libbpf` and `clang`

**PROBLEM:** I followed these steps

1) Build `libbpf`

```
git clone https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf.git
cd src
make
```

2) Copy `bpf_helpers.h` from my kernel src `/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/bpf_helpers.h`

3) Compile with

```
clang -S -I. -O2 -Wall -Werror -emit-llvm -c mine_kern.c -o - | llc -march=bpf -filetype=obj -o mine_kern.o
```

But as a result I have a lot of errors all related to the `bpf_helpers.h` content. e.g

```
In file included from mine_kern.c:7:
./bpf_helpers.h:75:11: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'BPF_FUNC_sock_ops_cb_flags_set'
        (void *) BPF_FUNC_sock_ops_cb_flags_set;
                 ^
```

**mine_kern.c**

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>    
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

SEC("socket")
int bpfrog1(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
        int proto = load_byte(skb, ETH_HLEN + offsetof(struct iphdr, protocol));

        if (proto == IPPROTO_ICMP && skb->pkt_type == PACKET_OUTGOING)
                return -1;
        else
                return 0;

}
char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

**QUESTIONS:**

The project tree is:

```
libbpf
  |src
    |libbpf.a
    |libbpf.so
    |...
libbpfebpf
  |bpf_headers.h
  |mine_kern.c
  |mine_user.c
```

how can I fix the error? After the fix  is enough to compile `_user.c` with `gcc` and `-L../libbpf/src` to link `libbpf.so` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kernel are you running? It looks like the `bpf_sock_ops_cb_flags_set()` BPF helper is not supported by your kernel (missing from `/usr/include/linux/bpf.h`). It was added in Linux 4.17, so if your kernel is older than this, remove its definition (and all subsequent helpers) from your `bpf_helpers.h`. It should not be a problem for compiling your program, unless you intended to use one of those more recent helpers.

Alternatively, upgrade your kernel.

And yes, I think it should be enough to pass the `-L` flag to gcc to tell it where to find the libbpf.

Comment: You are my new God anyway.
I 'm running 4.18.0-25-generic. 
I've installed 4.18.0 src code running sudo apt install linux-source-4.18.0, and then I've copied bpf_helpers.h from the kernel src code. Why there is this discrepancy?

Comment: I spend all day working with BPF, it's just normal I'm more familiar with it. Hmm if you run on 4.18, I don't know why you would get that error though. Do you have `FN(sock_ops_cb_flags_set)` in `/usr/include/linux/bpf.h? What are the other error messages you get, are they only for subsequent helper definitions?

Comment: I think I'll need 5 years to be familiar with it XD. 
As you said, I've tried to delete all helpers definitions within  bpf_helpers.h starting from sock_ops_cb_flags_set and clang compiled flawlessly. Still I don't understand why  there is difference between the kernel I'm running and the source code.

Comment: Theoretically there shouldn't be, if you pick the file from the sources at the same version as your own kernel. Not sure why this happened in your case. (If versions were different, error would be because `bpf_helpers.h` uses the definitions from /usr/include/linux/bpf.h, and of course if those definitions are not present there's an issue.)

Comment: Finally I did it , thanks a lot. Still 100000000000000 doubts.
At the end I used this line gcc -I. -I../libbpf/src/  mine_user.c -o mine_user ../libbpf/src/libbpf.a -lelf  but I didn't understand why it didn't work using -lbpf instead of ../libbpf/src/libbpf.a

Comment: I'm not sure. `gcc -o foo foo.c -L../libbpf/src/ -lbpf` worked for me on a similar project (`-lbpf` and other lib inclusions must be at the end of the line I believe), not sure what went wrong in your case.

Comment: did you also change LD_LIBRARY_PATH to use the dynamic library instead of the static?

Comment: Not that I remember of.